# Read the content of CSS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am getting a CSS file from the server, i want the content of that file and put that in a  tag in my body before anything else loads. Is there a way to read the content of a css file using Jquery or JavaScript?

Comment: There probably is, but why would you do this ?

Comment: I want to get the css which is client specific from the server and append it to document. I want that to load after every other css is loaded.

Comment: you should explain how you're getting that CSS from server. And also explain why you can't / don't want to load the CSS using standards (with `<style>` or `<link>` tag).

Comment: And why not just include it the regular way?

Comment: http://beta2.postify.com/public/clients/26/style.css is the css file I am getting from the server. For the question why I am not appending it to the head is that it doesn't work for all browsers. I just googled it and it was having some issue with some versions of FF.

Comment: Get data from the Database. And bind it to page in server side

Comment: That CSS file contains one simple rule that should work everywhere, and even if it doesn't it sure won't cause any problems ?

Comment: @adeneo I am not getting you what you are trying to say here.

Comment: I'm trying to say you can just include the file normally, and if you still don't want to do that, just append a link tag, don't get the files content etc,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to read this via AJAX, as said by [Superdrac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3563606/superdrac). Use the jQuery function [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to achieve what you want.

```
$.get("path/to/stylesheet.css");
```

But, if you are getting the file from elsewhere, where there's no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set, you need to build a little proxy to access the file. So, you can do something in PHP like:

```
<?php
    die(file_get_contents($_GET["url"]));
?>
```

And you save this as `proxy.php` and you have to change your `$.get()` function this way:

```
$.get("proxy.php?url=http://another.domain/path/to/stylesheet.css");
```

And the function gives you the contents of the external stylesheet file. If you want to load that inside a tag, for eg., a `<div id="ext-css">` tag, you can do this way:

```
$("#ext-css").load("proxy.php?url=http://another.domain/path/to/stylesheet.css");
```

Hope this helps you a bit to get started. But still I am confused, why do you want to do such a thing. Are you flicking the stylesheet from somewhere you should not do? `;)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a file with Javascript, use the ajax methods. Here is the .get which allow you to read a file.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I get this error when I am using ajax to get the content "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Comment: There is a lot of topics about this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-w